# How can I select value from max(id) row based on id from another table rows on MySql

Tags: database

I have products table with id , sku , amount, columns .
the id and sku are Unique columns.

```
       products table 
  ---------------------------                                
      sku         |  amount
  ----------------|----------
  1-13-013-000    |  765.00
  4-670-140-NB12  |  864.00
  4-670-153f-NS16 |  912.00
  5-616-40        |  86.00
```

Another table is movements with id , sku , balance
In this table only id is Unique.

```
       movements table           
  id |  sku           | balance
  ---|----------------|----------
  1  |  5-51-51       |  765.00
  2  |  5-616-40      |  11.00
  3  |  5-704-40      |  709.00
  4  |  5-616-40      |  67.00
  5  |  1-13-013-000  |  414.00
  6  |  5-704-40      |  415.00 
  7  |  4-670-140-NB12|  313.00 
  8  |  5-616-40      |  79.00
  9  |  1-83-019-2    |  11.00  
  10 |  5-616-40      |  86.00
  11 |  4-670-140-NB12|  811.00
  12 |  1-13-013-000  |  765.00
```

i want to compare and check the for every sku on products table if has movement
(so i need to check in movements table ) and to find the last movement by the highest id
in movements table and to compare the balance and amount.
 I would like to get this results

```
  --------------------------------------                                
      sku         |  amount    | balance
  ----------------|------------|--------
  1-13-013-000    |  765.00    | 765.00 
  4-670-140-NB12  |  864.00    | 811.00  <- No match 
  4-670-153f-NS16 |  912.00    |         <-no movement
  5-616-40        |  86.00     | 79.00
```

I dont need the remark `<- No match` and `<-no movement`
 Any help is appreciated!
 Thanks for reading,
 Alon

Comment: One note: your results table is incorrect.  The balance for 5-616-40 should be displayed as 86.00 (see Id #10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results you have seem incorrect if you're trying to get the `MAX` from the movements table.

```
id |  sku           | balance
---|----------------|----------
1  |  5-51-51       |  765.00
2  |  5-616-40      |  11.00
3  |  5-704-40      |  709.00
4  |  5-616-40      |  67.00
5  |  1-13-013-000  |  414.00
6  |  5-704-40      |  415.00 
7  |  4-670-140-NB12|  313.00 
8  |  5-616-40      |  79.00
9  |  1-83-019-2    |  11.00  
10 |  5-616-40      |  86.00    <-- Max of 5-616-40
11 |  4-670-140-NB12|  811.00   <-- Max of 
12 |  1-13-013-000  |  765.00   <-- Max of 1-13-013-000
```

This should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT p.sku, p.amount, m.balance
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT sku, MAX(balance) AS balance FROM movements
    GROUP BY sku) m ON m.sku = p.sku
```

**Result**

```
|             SKU | AMOUNT | BALANCE |
--------------------------------------
|    1-13-013-000 |    765 |     765 |
|  4-670-140-NB12 |    864 |     811 |
| 4-670-153f-NS16 |    912 |  (null) |
|        5-616-40 |     86 |      86 |
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e87b2/1)

Comment: He's trying to get the balance of the entry with the maximum id, rather than the maximum balance.

Comment: by MAX(id) he meant the latest balance in the movements table.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work:

```
SELECT
    p.Sku,
    p.Amount,
    m.Balance
FROM
    TestMovements AS m
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(Id) AS Id
        FROM
            TestMovements
        GROUP BY
            Sku
    ) AS MaxIds
    ON
        m.Id = MaxIds.Id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    TestProducts AS p
    ON
        m.Sku = p.Sku
```